# CSS related bug with Twitter timeline widget as jCarousel element in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter, jcarousel

I'm at a total loss on this one.

I have a simple Twitter timeline widget as a jCarousel element. Everything is just kind of "messed up." When in Chrome, the elements of the jCarousel fall over each other and don't properly slide out of the way. Sometimes, when I click on the center of a jcarousel element, the formatting fixes itself. When I remove the CSS that the twitter API loads, everything works fine.

Has anyone heard of anything like this before? Anyone know what sort of problem this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to contain the twitter widget in its own iframe so that the widget script can't affect the rest of the page.